# Cannot update item view in a list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to update an item in a `ListView` from the `onItemClick` method, like this:

```
((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)).setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
    {                    
        view.findViewById(R.id.line_load_progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ...
    }
});
```

In item's xml layout, I have the following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/line_load_progress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to happen is to show a progress bar since click on an item will start an AsyncTask with Network IO. Unfortunately, setting visibility to visible **does not have any effect** on the view.

Does anybody know why listview is not updated and what I can do with this?

Comment: you can using progress dialog and in your preexceute method of async display it

Comment: I tried this already, it has no effect either.

Comment: If you use a ViewFlipper with one dummy emptyview and the progressbar? On click event you change the flipper to the second child.

Comment: Without the rest of the layout and the complete progress bar tag, no-one is going to be able to tell you why it isnt becoming visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you can't directly change each element in your list view you you need to notify the listview there is change and it will call it's methods to making the changes

and you can making  index variable that hold the position of item clicked so in getView Method you can specify which list item clicked and change the layout of this item only

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is not about showing progress dialog, it is about showing progressbar element in a list view item.

Comment: ok could you post your xml layout and more details about your code??

Comment: are you using custom adapter ?? basically you can't directly change each element in your list view you you need to notify the listview there is change and it will call it's methods to making the changes , could you post your java code ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own adapter that extends ArrayAdapter, I can post my java code, but I tried calling ``notifyDataSetChanged()`` and it didn't help.

Comment: Thank you @mohammed, it seems that the issue is exactly in custom layout adapter which calls getView after I click on any item. And getView method reloads again invisible progress from XML. Could you please update your answer so I could accept it?